# sqlite delete problem on iPhone

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite

In my iPhone app, I'm trying to delete a row from an SQLite database. After the delete statement is executed the row seems to be deleted correctly, but after I restart the application the row is still there.
I'm using the code blow to delete the record. Any idea what could be the problem?

```
NSString *deleteSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM table1 WHERE actId=%d", actId];

char *errorMsg;

if (database == nil) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR db not initialized but trying to delete record!!!");
}else{
    if (sqlite3_exec(database, [deleteSQL UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errorMsg) != SQLITE_OK){
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error updating tables: %s", errorMsg);
        sqlite3_free(errorMsg);
        return NO;
    }   
}

NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE Successful"]);
```

Comment: Did you copy your database to a writable area, or are you trying to write to a sandbox area? Also, just to let you know, your assertion failure will kill your execution path, but the UIApplication will actually continue, basically leaking memory. Use NSLog or asl_log instead or ensure that you compile out assertions on release.

Comment: The database has to be in a writable place, because sql statements do work on the same table. Should I 'commit' somehow to make the changes persist?

Thanks for the tipp regarding the assertion.

Comment: @levi - that's not true at all. The iPhone uses sandboxing, so the file can appear to be in a write-able place, but those changes only occur in memory. When the application terminates, no actual changes persist on the device. Where did you create this database?

Comment: But how is it possible that inserts are working and deletes aren't? When the app starts I'm checking if the db file is available, and if not I'm copying it to that place.  The path is determined with the follwing method:

- (NSString *) dataFilePath:(NSString *)fileName 
{
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 
 return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
}

Comment: They wouldn't be, but *I* didn't have that information before :) and you're using the correct method to get a writable location, so that isn't the problem. You're sure that the deletes are really successful, right?

Comment: I have a tableview that displays the data in the db, and after I delete the records and reload the data, it dissapears form the tableview. However, when I restart the app, it's still there.

Comment: That's just so strange. Does it happen in the Simulator as well as on the device?

Comment: I just noticed that the insert isn't working either. It worked in the past but since inplementing the delete feature it doesn't. So it might well be some writing error. Any idea how I could check if the db is writable?

Comment: now the strange thing is that right after copying and opening the database (copied from the bundle) I can insert some initial recrods which remain persistent. But after that at some point something changes because I can't insert any record

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !
I've solved my problem. Although I don't understand exactly all the details.  The problem was the in my 'loading code' I forgot to call sqlite3_finalize for the statements. Not sure why but this influenced somehow future inserts and deletes.  Adding sqlite3_finalize to the data loading method solved the problem.

Comment: Oh, I'm glad you solved it! If you're using a prepared statement you have to call sqlite3_reset() or sqlite3_finalize(), it's mandatory :) If you were calling reset(), then perhaps there is some caching going on that never gets flushed if the application terminates without calling finalize()...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved this problem. Although I don't understand exactly all the details.  The problem was the in my 'loading code' I forgot to call sqlite3_finalize for the statements. Not sure why but this influenced somehow future inserts and deletes.  Adding sqlite3_finalize to the data loading method solved the problem.